# Regarding Posts

Tags: posts, images

I have several questions

1. How to limit characters in the post?
2. How to ensure every posting require images upload?

That's all, appreciate if anyone can help..

Answer (score 1):

for your first quetion : you can either use the excerpt() instead of the_content() in your loop, or you can use this function below :

```
function limitcontent($limit) {
  $content = explode(' ', get_the_content(), $limit);
  if (count($content)>=$limit) {
    array_pop($content);
    $content = implode(" ",$content).'...';
  } else {
    $content = implode(" ",$content);
  } 
  $content = preg_replace('/\[.+\]/','', $content);
  $content = apply_filters('the_content', $content); 
  $content = str_replace(']]>', ']]&gt;', $content);
  return $content;
}
```

usage :

```
<?php echo excerpt(25); ?>
```

for your second question : <strike>You can not .</strike>

<strike>(well - not in an easy manner, it would involve hooking to the pre_post_save , and regecting a save if an image was not attached to a post - and this function is not something you would write on-the-fly without checking - at least not me )</strike>

<strike>but , if you MUST have an image for each post , you can use a different approach, which I have used many times, which is to define a default image for a post with no attachments  . you can use this by category, by taxonemy, or even define a default post_thumbnail if none is defined by users.</strike>

edit **- you CAN -** after 5 minutes of rethinking - here is how to force image upload on post :

```
add_action( 'pre_post_update', 'krembo99_no_image_no_publish' );

function krembo99_no_image_no_publish()
{
global $post;
$attachments = get_children( array( 'post_parent' => $post->ID, 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'post_mime_type' => 'image') );
//$attachments = get_children( array('post_parent' => $post->ID, 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'post_mime_type' => 'image') );
//if((!$attachments)) {
if(count($attachments) === 0){
wp_die( 'you can not publish a post without an image, please update attachments !' );
}
}
```

someone might want to change the wp_die with the warning bar , but this function works now . 
* - not fully tested, only on posts...

Comment: in which file does this code i must embed?

Comment: the code goes in functions.php and the execution code in your loop